# Random out of memory Issues in a WordPress application for Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, error-logging, php-ini, access-log

I have a WordPress application running on a Xampp over a Windows machine.

Here, arbitrary "out of memory" fatal errors are encountered in file `wp-includes/wp-db.php`. I checked with my .ini file and found the required configuration as:

```
max_execution_time=600
memory_limit=2048M
post_max_size=750M
```

Nothing overriding in wp-config.php as well.

And size of my access log file of Apache is 165 MB and size of error log file of Apache is 2.24 MB.

I believe one or more of the above given detail is the reason behind this random out of memory issue.

What's the correction needed and what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you restartet your server after changing memory limit?

Comment: Yes I did restarted it @ManuelMannhardt

Comment: Do you have any modules installed, which could use a lot of memory? Had that problem with Drupal once. If yes or you are not sure, try to disable modules until you dont get memory errors.

Comment: Any hint on where that error occurs, like file and line number?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the file is wp-includes/wp-db.php

Comment: You should also check the `wp-config.php` file (WP tends to override the php.ini settings)

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt do you mean, apache modules or the wordpress plugins?

Comment: I mean WordPress modules, they tend to make WP (or any CMS/such system as WP really) pretty slow.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson nothing overriding in wp-config.php

Comment: I feel like whenever server goes to log a request in access log file, it has to access the file of 165 MB and 1 lakh 54 thousand line, so is that could be a reason behind?

Comment: Do I have the right values for ini file? depending of each other?

Comment: Apache's access log doesn't affect PHP in that way.